# How to make a discrete width in CSS?

Tags: css

Here's an example in JS: http://jsfiddle.net/0gbd58r2/

```
var WIDTH = 18;
var sizeUpdate = function() {
    this.style.width = ((document.body.clientWidth / WIDTH) | 0) * WIDTH + 'px';
}

var lorem = document.getElementById('lorem');

var updater = sizeUpdate.bind(lorem);
updater();

onresize = updater;
```

[image]

Is it possible to implement this behaviour in CSS **without generating a lot of @media queries for every possible width**?

Comment: and what is the purpose of this?

Comment: Can explain further on what you are trying to achieve? It is not clear what you actually want to do. The effect from you java script could be achieved with borders/padding/margins.

Comment: What is a single pipeline operator in this context? ` | 0` nevermind bitwise derp

Comment: You want to snap the width to every 18 pixels? Is there a particular reason for doing this? Regardless, there's nothing like this available. However, you could use a preprocessor like SCSS to dynamically generate the media queries.

Comment: `this.style.width = ((document.body.clientWidth / WIDTH) | 0) * WIDTH + 'px';
}` Isn't it a strong possibility that `document.body.clientWidth` is a float (if resized especially)? If so, then the expression would give unexpected results because bitwise uses integers.

Comment: Can you describe what problem are you trying to solve with this code?

Comment: @JonP achieving the same with margins would have the same problem, wouldn't it? The only difference is that a half of modulo would be used instead of quotient.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst even with upper limit to possible viewport width, it would lead to hundreds of queries that way. It's no worth it. I specified explicitly in the question that the solution should be something other, if possible.

Comment: @zer00ne the purpose of |0 is exactly to make a float-to-integer conversion (like Math.floor(), but shorter). It's used that way in asm.js.

Comment: @AlonEitan the purpose is to make a centered block that fits as many monospace glyphs as possible, without additional gaps in it.

Comment: @bodqhrohro I thought floats get truncated ex, `0.542 | 0` the float becomes `0`

Comment: @zer00ne so what's wrong with it? Rounding up is not needed in this case, it will cause overflow.

Comment: I haven't read your current explanation of what your function actually does, but before I do, I'll guess that any remaining numbers to the right of decimal should be removed and a length of zero is ok, correct?

Comment: @zer00ne yes. Zero-width is an edge case though.